# Which Parsley.js method should I use for adding/updating accessibility attributes?

Tags: parsley.js

I have a parsley-config.js file in which I have successfully added lots of customizations to parsley, utilizing the methods described on Parsley's [defaults.js documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html). However I'm having trouble figuring out how to add some attributes to elements upon validation. the `classHandler` method looked promising but only ran on initialization, not when validating.

Here's a little of the code I'm thinking of using. I just need to know what Parsley method I should stick it in.

```
var ParsleyConfig = {
  mysteryMethod: function(parsleyField) {
    var $field = parsleyField.$element;
    // Acessibility attributes based on error or not
    if (parsleyField.validationResult.length > 0) {
        $field.attr({'aria-describedby': parsleyId, 'aria-invalid': true});
    } else {
        $field.removeAttr('aria-describedby').attr({'aria-invalid': false});
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is probably to listen to [the events](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-events-list) `field:success` and `field:error` or similar...